# How do i import multiple images from a folder in python/pygame

Tags: python, import

I've tried importing the folder and then importing all from the folder.
`import FOLDERNAME`
`from FOLDERNAME import *`
i cant think of any other way to import multiple images from a folder

Comment: I'm assuming you want something more elegant than ```pygame.image.load('PATH') ```

Answer (score 0):

Do this: `pygame.image.load('PATH')`

Answer (score 0):

lets suppose your file names are "x.png","y.png","z.png" and is located in the same directory,then you could do:

```
filenames = ['x','y','z']
files = []
for i in filenames:
 files.append(pygame.image.load("{name}.png".format(name = i))
```

This way you can import multiple images.